# Is there a default ExecutorService or am I doomed to create one and maintain it to get Future objetcs?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, java-7

The only way to get a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), from what I understand, is to use an `ExecutorService`, which is obtained for instance via `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` (btw, how do you how many threads to use? is there some thumb rule?).

So what I don't understand, is whether am I supposed to use:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
```

And then save it (e.g. in some top level `IoC`) and call the `executorService` whenever I need new `Future`?

Isn't there like a default Java's built-in `ExecutorService` I can used, thus avoiding the nag of `ExecutorService` initialization and maintenance?

Comment: What do you mean by "default ExecutorService"? What do you want to do?

Comment: @Tunaki, in `C#`, it is managed automatically by the framework (`.net`), you don't have to create a thread-pool yourself

Comment: In plain Java you have to do that yourself. Several frameworks provide defaults, https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/Using-as-a-generic-library#the-global-event-loop for example. How many threads you need depends on the task. CPU bound tasks roughly as many as you have CPU cores, tasks that wait for IO most of the time (e.g. for http responses) potentially many more. Depends on how much IO the thing you wait on can handle. [`FutureTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) also gives you futures without executors ( execute them in plain `Thread`s).

Comment: "The only way to get a Future...is to use an `ExecutorService`" No, you can just instantiate one (or at least, a concrete subclass of one, e.g. `FutureTask`).

Comment: @Tar your question is a bit like asking "is there a default `String`?": there is no "default" which satisfies enough peoples' requirements in general such that it would be considered useful. If you want something that meets your requirements, create it.

Comment: `Executors.newWorkStealingPool` will use all available cores. You are supposed to create a scheduler for your application yourself, not create a new one everytime you want to run a task

Comment: @AndyTurner, when I down-vote, I leave a comment explaining the reason, so the OP can learn from it. Anyway, see how much I learned from this question (after Googling half a day!): `ExecutorService` is not the only way to issue a `Future`, there is no default like in `.net` (which if isn't "satisfying", you aren't obliged to use, you can create new one, so everybody wins), and there's the `Executors.newWorkStealingPool` which is very valuable! (thanks Lev!)

Comment: @zapl, thanks, the [`Netty Project`](https://github.com/netty), especially the [`global event loop`](https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/Using-as-a-generic-library#the-global-event-loop) look good!

Comment: There are *lots* of ways to get a `Future`. From an asynchronous socket channel, for example. Some of these subsystems that supply `Futures` have their own internal executors, and some of them you can supply your own, or both. Your question needs to be more precise.

Answer (score 11):

> default Java's built-in ExecutorService

[ForkJoinPool.commonPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) - *Returns the **common pool instance**. This pool is statically constructed; its run state is unaffected by attempts to shutdown() or shutdownNow(). However this pool and any ongoing processing are **automatically terminated** upon program System.exit(int)...*

```
Future<?> future = ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> { /* something to do */}) ;
```

But there is a more **modern way**: [**CompletableFuture**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { /* something to do */});
```

Comment: CompletableFuture just uses this: "All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() (unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is created to run each task)."  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Comment: CompletableFuture is not a replacement for Executors(i.e. commonPool), but rather providing a library to use this Executors efficiently and conveniently. Directly to solve your problem, you could create your own Executors.new***ThreadPool(...) with the required level of parallelism, and use it explicitly when calling CompletableFuture(.., myExecutor).

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't there like a default Java's built-in ExecutorService I can use...?

There is in Java8.

Read the Javadoc for `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...)`.